# How to count the number of even/odd numbers in a spark dataframe column?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a spark DataFrame with many columns and I want to count how many odd/even numbers I have in a specific column, `count`. The `count` column is a `LongType()`.

Let say I have the foillowing Dataframe df:

```python
# Id     count
# 2342      5
# 1267      4
# 3276      2
# 6745      1
```

I try to convert the col to a list:

```python
list1=list(df.select("count"))
```

and then

```python
odd_count = len(list(filter(lambda x: (x%2 != 0) , list1))) 
even_count = len(list(filter(lambda x: (x%2 == 0) , list1))) 

print("Even numbers in the list: ", even_count) 
print("Odd numbers in the list: ", odd_count)
```

I expect just 2 numbers, the amount of odd numbers and the amount of even numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to a `list` or calling `collect` in order to do the aggregation in python defeats the purpose of using spark. Just do a simple `groupBy`:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df.groupBy((col("count")%2).alias("isOdd")).count().show()
#+-----+-----+
#|isOdd|count|
#+-----+-----+
#|    1|    2|
#|    0|    2|
#+-----+-----+
```

And if you wanted those values as python variables, you can call collect *after* the aggregation (since the amount of data being passed back is small).

```python
counts = df.groupBy((col("count")%2).alias("isOdd")).count().collect()
odd_count = filter(lambda x: (x["isOdd"] == 1), counts)[0]["count"]
even_count = filter(lambda x: (x["isOdd"] == 0), counts)[0]["count"]

print("Even numbers in the list: {}".format(even_count)) 
#Even numbers in the list: 2

print("Odd numbers in the list: {}".format(odd_count))
#Odd numbers in the list: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#  Convert the column to list
lst = df.select('count').collect()

#  Odd and Even Count
sum(1 for sublst in lst for item in sublst if item%2!= 0)
>>>2
sum(1 for sublst in lst for item in sublst if item%2== 0)
>>>2
```